# admin panel on port 2030 not opening in cent-os web panel

Tags: ftp, sftp, centos6, dedicated-server

I  have dedicated server with cent-os and proxmox ve. Also made virtual machine with centos 6 and centos webpanel in proxmox. From last four month I'm using this and everything is working properly mean I'm able to open `mysite:2030` (admin panel). But from today morning, it is not opening, I don't know why is this happening. But I'm able to access all files through ftp(21) and also able to access sftp(22). Please help me configuring it so I will able to open admin panel(Control Panel).Thanks. I asked this question on https://serverfault.com/ but still have no reply, so I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to look at your iptables rules? 
As far as I know, centOS blocks everything, allowing only the ports present in the rules in the iptables.

Comment: Please tell me how do I check it?

Answer (score 0):

After trying so many methods I searched on net related iptables, I got one best solution, now everything is working like a charm. And applied below command with root access using putty.

1)First I tried this commands:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2030 -j ACCEPT //press enter
service iptables restart //press enter
```

2)then below commands:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2030 -j ACCEPT //enter
/etc/init.d/iptables stop //enter
/etc/init.d/iptables start //enter
reboot //rebooted server
```